# How to get fullname of the searched result in reactjs

Tags: javascript

The code below works fine. it check if username already exist and then trigger an alert.

**Here is my issue:** I want to display fullname for the searched result. if I say
`alert(records[0].fullname)`, it will alert the fullname of the first row.

how do I alert fullname for the searched result of the existing username

```js
function app() {
  const tab = base.getTableByNameIfExists('users_table');
  const records = useRecords(tab);

  // check if username nancy already exist and then fetch or alerts its fullname for searched result
  if (records.filter(record => record.username === 'nancy').length > 0) {
    alert('This username already exist');
    //get fullname for search result where the username already exist
    //alert(records[0].fullname);
    //alert(records[0].username);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question but something like `const user = records.find(record => record.username === 'nancy'); if (user) { alert(user.fullname) }`

Comment: Thanks alot, its working now. You can update it as the right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get a single result (if it exists) you can use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead of `filter` (which returns **an Array** of objects). If `find` finds nothing it returns `undefined`.

So

```js
const user = records.find(record => record.username === 'nancy');
// if there is no such a user, the variable "user" will be undefined,
// therefor "falsy" so the if condition will not be executed
if (user) { alert(user.fullname) }
```